# Specifying Kotlin coroutine context for each function or leaving this to the caller function? Which one is recommended?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am new to Kotlin for Android development, and I was wondering which of the following approaches is recommended when working with Coroutine?

#### 1. Specifying coroutine context at each function declaration

In this approach, each function will overwrite the caller context to the appropriate one.

**My Assumption:** The benefit is that the caller function doesn't need to know about the inners of the function it calls.

```kotlin
suspend fun callee() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    httpClient.get("https://google.com")
}

suspend fun caller() {
    callee()
    callee()
}
```

#### 2. Delegate picking the correct context to the caller

Here, we leave the decision to the caller function, meaning it can pick any context appropriate for that use case.

**Please Challenge:** This lowers the code complexity and the overhead of context switching.

```kotlin
suspend fun callee() {
    httpClient.get("https://google.com")
}

suspend fun caller() {
    // Specify context only once
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        callee()
        callee()
    }
}
```

#### 2½. Libraries already take care of this!

Since I use KTOR client, can I assume that the library already picks the correct context and I don't need to specify them?

```kotlin
suspend fun callee() {
    // Assumption: Ktor will run the request in correct context
    httpClient.get("https://google.com")
}

suspend fun caller() {
    callee()
    callee()
}
```

Comment: I found this answer https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#main-safe which I now realise was being iterated in the other answers but I didn't understand them. Essentially, every suspend function should be callable from the UI context. Therefore, context switching to Dispatchers.IO should be done within any suspend function that requires it. This seems like the best solution, as you can simply take it for granted that any suspend function you call can be called from the main/UI thread, and any context switching is handled internally by the source function.

Answer (score 4):

1. and 2.5. By design, suspend functions are required to never block the thread. That means two things:

- We can call them directly from any other suspend function. We shouldn't need to switch the dispatcher in order to call a suspend function.
- These functions have to correctly switch to another dispatcher if needed. Or use asynchronous processing internally.

If you see a suspend function which blocks the thread or expects to be called in a specific thread, then this function was implemented incorrectly.

Of course, we can sometimes ignore such rules when implementing an internal, private functionality inside a class. Maybe we would like to e.g. split a bigger block of code performing I/O into multiple smaller functions, but we still need them to be suspendable. In that case it probably makes sense to switch to `Dispatchers.IO` only once, at the entry point.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your dilemma wouldn't exist in the first place. Since you're calling a suspendable function, there is no need to specify a dispatcher. A suspendable function must work equally well regardless of the dispatcher used, and it should never block the thread it's called on. It is the implementor's responsibility to call `withContext` as needed to maintain this promise.

The dilemma exists primarily due to the big success Kotlin Coroutines had early on, while they were still experimental. The feature got massive attention and lots of web material was written at that time, when there was virtually no library support for it. Many examples floating on the web are now outdated and, unfortunately, misleading. This is compounded by the fact that adding a `withContext(IO)` doesn't hurt correctness, it's just unnecessary.

Comment: To clarify, `httpClient.get` is also suspendable. None of the functions in the functions in the examples I wrote are thread blocking. However, developers are supposed to pick one of the Dispatchers (IO, Main, Default, Unconfined), but the examples I found so far are inconsistent.

Comment: The web is full of misleading examples. You never need to switch dispatchers when calling a suspendable function. Try without it and see if it blocks anything. It shouldn't, and if it does, that's on the implementor of that function. A serious bug.